# composer install Laravel

Tags: php, composer

Клонировал репозиторий с гита, но после ввода в консоль `composer install` получаю ошибки

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.4.1 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.1].
    - intervention/image 2.4.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for stripe/stripe-php v6.4.1 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v6.4.1].
    - stripe/stripe-php v6.4.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for facebook/webdriver 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.5.0].
    - facebook/webdriver 1.5.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - intervention/image 2.4.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - tcg/voyager dev-master requires intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.1].
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager dev-master -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[dev-master].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - E:\www\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-7.1\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

может кто-нибудь сталкивался, что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишет же, что для работы пакетов которые устанавливаются с laravel нужны дополнения php, такие как fileinfo , curl.

Консоль так же пишет что в вашем опенсервере можно включить эти дополнения раскомментировав нужные дополнения в php.ini

E:\www\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-7.1\php.ini

Вроде в openserver быстро можно отредактировать php.ini, если кликнуть на флажок опенсервера далее Дополнительно, далее Конфигурация и выбираешь php.
И в редакторе откроется php.ini